# ecommerce for sharepoint 2010

Tags: third-party-software, e-commerce

We have a fairly large 2010 extranet platform that we do a lot of development on. We have have some basic ecommerce needs (maybe a few dozen items, online payment, etc) and I'd to avoid having to build an ecommerce solution from scratch that integrates into Sharepoint 2010.

I know Microsoft Commerce 2009 integrates but I'm wondering how much, or if there are some other products out there that do a good job?

Answer (score 1):

I'm looking to do the same, but haven't come up with a good answer.

The license costs for Commerce Server are massive - so not an option for me.

SharePoint simply is not an e-commerce platform, and was never designed to be - it's a collaboration platform, so this is never going to be straight forward.

I would suggest going with a completely seperate e-commerce solution, and try to embed it in SharePoint using i-frames. Or, what about implementing simple Pay-Pal buy-now buttons in SharePoint form web parts? It might work.